# jquery label value and input grouping

Tags: jquery

I have a form that I am creating that has values that need to change based on checked values etc.

I know I'm overthinking the hell out of this.

```
<div>   
   <span align="right">Skill 1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  
   <span class="amt" name="s_Skill1">3</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input name="i_Skill1" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

so this particular skill costs 3 points, but if one of the other checkboxes is checked, it's only 1 point.  I'm having some issues with identifying when something is checked, vs changing the value.

```
if ($("#i_Skill1").is(':checked')) {
            alert("changing radio button");
            $("#s_Skill1").text("0");
        }
```

It seems like I'm having to jump through a lot of hoops, like I should be able to change values and identify what I want/need to change.

Here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mattcushing/K5szE/31/  Yeah, I know, it's Dungeons and Dragons, but it was something my son asked for and I thought it'd be a good foray into jquery :)

Answer (score 1):

`#id` is the id selector, you have to change the `name` to `id`.

OR there is multiple div like that, you'd better to use `class`.

```
<div>   
   <span align="right">Skill 1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  
   <span class="amt" name="s_Skill1" class="s_Skill">3</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input name="i_Skill1" class="i_Skill" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Then:

```
$('.i_Skill').each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).siblings('.s_Skill').text('0');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be referencing the elements *by `name`*, not by `id` as they don't have one specified in this case.

```
if ($('span[name="i_Skill1"]').is(':checked')) {
    alert("changing radio button");
    $('input[name="s_Skill1"]').text("0");
}
```